# Kotlin - Function that Writes to a Stream of Unspecified Type

Tags: c++, kotlin, stream, stdout

in C++, there is a concept of an `ostream`. `cout` is an `ostream`, as is an `ofstream`. In this way you can define a function that takes an ostream and writes to it so that the caller can decide where he wants the function to write to.

Is it possible to achieve the same effect in kotlin: defining a function that determines where (possibly the console) it writes to at runtime? Obviously `if` or `when` statements don't count.

Comment: @gidds so how would I make a Writer point to a file or stdout as needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin (and Java) have two equivalents: [`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) for byte streams, and [`Writer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) for character streams. These are both abstract classes, with many concrete subclasses writing to different places.

To take the simpler case:

- If you want to write byte data to a file, you can create a [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) instance which writes to a given filename.  (That implements `OutputStream`.)
- Or if you want to write to stdout, you can use [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) directly.  (That is also an `OutputStream`.)
- Or if you have a network [`Socket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html), you can call its [`getOutputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream()) method, which gives you an `OutputStream`.
- Or there are implementations that can write to a byte array, or a pipe, or a CORBA stream, or…

So if you have some code that uses an `OutputStream`, you could provide it with an instance of any of those classes, and when that calls [`OutputStream.write()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write-byte:A-) it will write to the appropriate place.

(In practice, you often wrap it in a [`BufferedOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) for efficiency.)

It's very similar for a `Writer`, too, but in those cases you generally have to tell it which character encoding to use.  (Though in many cases you can leave it to the platform default, which is usually UTF-8.)

- So if you want to write character data to a file, you can create a [`FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) instance which writes to a given filename.
- Or if you want to write to stdout you can create an [`OutputStreamWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) around `System.out`.
- And so on.

Again, if your code is written to accept any `Writer`, then it will work regardless of where it writes to, and there's a [`BufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) wrapper for efficiency.

---

There are equivalent classes for input, too: [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) for byte streams, and [`Reader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) for character streams, both with lots of implementations for different sources.

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps in java and kotlin :

1. Get the **InputStream** or **OutputStream**, either from file or network or any other resource that can provide you these Streams. (usages and names of Streams vary depending upon abstractions they provide)
2. You can use these **Streams** to read or write to them which eventually reads from or writes to the underlying Resource.(eg. a file)
3. At the end of operations you need to close the respective Streams using **close()** method.
4. Then you may or may not close the Resource depending on your use case.

I would recommend that you follow the Kotlin documentation.

Must see the usage of ["use"](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html). ( It is like Java's try-with-resource)